# Capturing data on who a product was purchased for

Tags: checkout, customer

We're going to be using Magento to sell professional development course registrations to various customers, and some of those courses are purchased for someone else. For example, the head of HR for a company may want to purchase 12 course seats for company employees, but won't be attending the course themselves. We need to be able to ask the course purchaser during the checkout process, the names, emails, and phone numbers of the people who will be attending the course.

Is this data best stored as a customer, with some kind of special attribute, or is there a better place to store this data.

For an example of what we're trying to do, check out the Magento training catalog: http://magento.com/training/catalog/developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is achievable but it will require a little bit of customisation. The quick and easy way would be to make a custom module, create an additional table `sales_attendees` that could look like this :

`attendee_id`, `order_id`, `name`, `email`, `phone`

Then on the last step of the checkout, you can have some input fields to capture the data you need (if you want an example on how to do that, `Biebersdorf_CustomerOrderComment` is a good one to work from)

Comment: I would also go for an extended comment on checkout, so an attribute related to the quote, rather then attribute related to the customer, unless it's very likely that there will be repeat orders for (a subset of) the same employees.

Comment: Repeat orders for employees are a distinct possibility, but couldn't I just pull that information from previous quotes/orders?

Comment: @NikolasAdair You totally can. I can imagine you can identify them by their email address (as long as you make this field required).

Answer (score 0):

Well Basically its all depends on your own requirement that what exactly you want to see.

Basically, the person which will generate order will always be consider as an Customer in Magento, Now further tasks depends on you, rather you want to add attendees as an separate entity or you want to add them as a new customer.

To fulfill above requirement we need do different level of customizations and module development.